# Can I share cuda GPU device memory between host processes?

Tags: linux, ipc, cuda, gpu, interprocess

Is it possible to have two or more linux host processes that can access the same *device memory*?
I have two processes streaming high data rate between them and I don't want to bring the data back out of the GPU to the host in process A just to pass it to process B who will memcpy h2d back into the GPU.

Combining the multiple processes into a single process is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of the CUDA APIs is that this cannot be done. The device pointers are relative to a given CUDA context, and there's no way to share those between processes.

Comment: moreover, cuda context is contained to individual threads.
So you cannot even share GPU data between cpu threads.
this is as far as I know

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the answer nonetheless

Comment: @BrianTheLion, that forum post is about sharing *host* memory, not *device* memory.

Comment: It looks like the answer may have changed in recent years according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819216/interprocess-communication-cuda/19821387#19821387